# Изменить шаблон вывода последних новостей

Tags: joomla

Здравствуйте. На главной в движке Joomla выводятся последние новости.
Каким образом можно изменить сам шаблон этого вывода(внешний вид). Я не могу найти файл который отвечает за это. То есть мне нужно изменить саму разметку.

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копируем файл:

```
/modules/mod_articles_latest/tmpl/default.php
```

в папку:

```
/templates/yoortmpl/html/mod_articles_latest/
```

Редактируем этот файл на свое усмотрение в /templates/yoortmpl/html/mod_articles_latest/ (вместо yoortmpl - название папки вашего шаблона)